# Lunchroom Question: primes adding up to counting numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

Our lunchtime group got into another math related discussion.  I apologize in advance if this isn't a rigorous question, as none of us are professional mathematicians. This is the question:

Is it possible to write every counting number (1, 2, 3, etc.) as a sum of no more than two primes, or as the sum of 1 and one prime?

Can anyone suggest links to articles or discussions about this?

I found the Goldbach Conjecture, which is about even counting numbers.  Is there anything else?

Comment: For odd numbers, neither two primes nor $1$ and one prime are sufficient in general, but $3$ primes are probably enough.

Comment: If the Goldbach Conjecture is true, every even number greater than $2$ is the sum of two primes and every odd number greater than $5$ is the sum of $3$ primes.

Comment: For any $n$, if $2n+1$ and $2n+3$ are both composite, then $2n+3$ is a counter-example. So we get $27, 35, 51, 57,\ldots$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly not every odd integer $n>1$ is the sum of two primes. Already $27$ is a counterexample. However, every odd $n>1$ is indeed the sum of *at most* five primes. This is a very nice result, see [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/every-odd-integer-larger-than-1-is-the-sum-of-at-most-five-primes/). If we consider the other condition whether $n=1+p$ is possible, the situation is not better. In general, $n-1$ need not be prime.
Even if we combine the two conditions, there are many counterexamples.

Comment: thank you very much, i guess we went deeper than we expected